# How do I configure the Auth0 sign up (registration) form to require users to enter their password twice?

Tags: auth0, auth0-lock

I want my Auth0 registration form (but not the login form) to require users to enter their password twice to confirm they typed it correctly, but the [Lock Configuration Options](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/lock-configuration) don't include such a feature.

How can I specify that users must enter their password twice when registering?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`additionalSignUpFields`](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/lock-configuration#additionalsignupfields-array-) feature to include an additional 2nd password field, as [demonstrated here](https://community.auth0.com/t/how-to-add-a-re-enter-password-field-to-universal-login-experience-sign-up/110581/3) in the Branding -> Universal Login page:

```js
additionalSignUpFields: [
  {
    name: "repeat_password",
    placeholder: Repeat Password,          
    type: "password",
    validator: function (repeat_password) {
      const passwordField = document.getElementsByName("password")[0];

      if (passwordField === undefined || passwordField.value !== repeat_password) {
        return {
          valid: false,
          hint: 'Passwords do not match',
        };
      }
      return { valid: true };
    },
  },
],
```

However, this will cause the user's 2nd password field (`repeat_password`) to be stored in the user's Auth0 metadata. If this is unacceptably insecure, you can use Javascript to include a 2nd password field which is not part of the `additionalSignUpFields`:

```js
function validatePassword(e) {
    var pwElmt = document.getElementById('1-password') // Auth0 default password field
    var confirmPwElmt = document.getElementById('confirm-password') // Our 'confirm password' field

    if (pwElmt.value == confirmPwElmt.value) {
        // Passwords match so show submit button:
        pwElmt.style.border = 'none'
        confirmPwElmt.style.border = 'none'
        document.getElementById('1-submit').style.display = 'block'
        return true;
    } else {
        // Passwords don't match so hide submit button:
        pwElmt.style.border = '1px solid red'
        confirmPwElmt.style.border = '1px solid red'
        document.getElementById('1-submit').style.display = 'none'
        return false;
    }
}

var pwTimer = null;
var pwElmt = null;

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    console.log('Setting up pwTimer...');
    // Do this repeatedly until the element we want comes into view, i.e. the registration page:
    pwTimer = setInterval(
        function () {
            pwElmt = document.querySelector('.auth0-lock-input-block.auth0-lock-input-fname');
            if (pwElmt) {
                console.log('Got pwElmt!');
                clearInterval(pwTimer);

                // Inject the password confirmation 
                let confirmPasswordHTML = '<div class="auth0-lock-input-block auth0-lock-input-show-password"><div class="auth0-lock-input-block auth0-lock-input-password"><div class="auth0-lock-input-wrap auth0-lock-input-wrap-with-icon"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" width="11px" height="14px" viewBox="0 0 13 16" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" class="auth0-lock-icon auth0-lock-icon-box"><g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><g transform="translate(-288.000000, -1508.000000)" fill="#888888"><path d="M299,1523.998 L290,1523.998 C288.896,1523.998 288,1523.102 288,1521.999 L288,1515.999 C288,1514.895 288.896,1513.998 290,1513.998 L290,1513.998 L290,1512.499 C290,1510.015 292.015,1507.999 294.5,1507.999 C296.985,1507.999 299,1510.015 299,1512.499 L299,1513.999 C300.104,1513.999 301,1514.895 301,1515.999 L301,1521.999 C301,1523.103 300.104,1523.998 299,1523.998 L299,1523.998 Z M298,1512.499 C298,1510.566 296.433,1508.999 294.5,1508.999 C292.567,1508.999 291,1510.566 291,1512.499 L291,1513.998 L298,1513.998 L298,1512.499 L298,1512.499 Z M300,1515.999 C300,1515.446 299.552,1514.998 299,1514.998 L290,1514.998 C289.447,1514.998 289,1515.446 289,1515.999 L289,1521.999 C289,1522.551 289.447,1522.998 290,1522.998 L299,1522.998 C299.552,1522.998 300,1522.551 300,1521.999 L300,1515.999 L300,1515.999 Z M294.5,1520.998 C294.224,1520.998 294,1520.774 294,1520.498 L294,1517.498 C294,1517.223 294.224,1516.999 294.5,1516.999 C294.776,1516.999 295,1517.223 295,1517.498 L295,1520.498 C295,1520.774 294.776,1520.998 294.5,1520.998 L294.5,1520.998 Z"></path></g></g></svg><input type="password" id="confirm-password" name="confirm-password" class="auth0-lock-input" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="none" value="" aria-label="Confirm password" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="confirm your password"></div></div></div>';

                pwElmt.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', confirmPasswordHTML)
                console.log('Injected password confirmation')

                document.getElementById('1-password').addEventListener('input', validatePassword)
                document.getElementById('confirm-password').addEventListener('input', validatePassword)

                // Prevent Enter from submitting the form:
                var authForm = document.querySelector('.auth0-lock-form');
                if (authForm) {
                    authForm.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
                        if (event.key === 'Enter' || event.keyCode === 13) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                }
            } else {
                console.log('Still waiting for pwElmt...')
            }
        },
        1000 // Every second
    )
});
```

This uses `setInterval()` to wait until the `Sign Up` tab is showing, then injects a 2nd password field after the first one. As the user types into either of the password fields, the `validatePassword()` function is called which determines whether the passwords match; if so, it removes the red border around the fields and displays the `Sign Up` button; if not, it adds a red border around the fields and hides the `Sign Up` button.

It also traps the `Enter` key to prevent users from submitting the form by hitting `Enter`. This way, the passwords must match before the form can be submitted.